# How to a execute a Roslaunch command inside a running container

Tags: docker, containers, ros

I am trying to run autoware with carla. Autoware is running as a container in linux machine. now  after starting the container, when I want to launch my launch files to start the auotware nodes using
**roslaunch carla_autoware_agent carla_autoware_agent.launch town:=Town04 synchronous_mode:=true**

with out entering into the container , I am getting the following error
**OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "roslaunch": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown**

I did try to run the same with docker exec but still its not working.

How do I run the roslaunch command in a linux machine without entering into the container either using shell script.

Comment: what are the docker commands that you use to start your environment and then run the command (the one giving error)?

Comment: This is the command used to start the container 
docker run \
    -d \
    -it --rm \
    --volume=$(pwd)/autoware-contents:/home/autoware/autoware-contents:ro \
    --env="DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}" \
    --privileged \
    --net=host \
    $RUNTIME \
    carla-autoware:latest

after the container is up and running I want to run  "roslaunch carla_autoware_agent carla_autoware_agent.launch town:=Town04 synchronous_mode:=true" that is giving me error

Comment: The image is not publicly available so I can't test it. If you built it, then the command you try to run should go into the ENTRYPOINT or CMD. Since the command `roslaunch` is not found, probably the environment is not setup correctly. You should run a simple shell inside a container based on this image and investigate a bit where this binary is located (like with `find`). Once you find it, the ways to fix the issue should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the way I resolved it was to add a script in the /usr/local/bin called rc.sh

The contents of rc.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

roscore &
```

You can use roslaunch proj proj & here instead of roscore &, but make sure you source your setup.bash for your project.

Then run your docker image as normal with:

```
docker run -dit --all_other_options tag:1.1
```

Next run the following to execute script:

```
docker exec -i container_ID rc.sh
```

This is because docker was dealing with to many flags for me. This should work without you having to enter the container. To get the script in the docker container you can use the following inside your Dockerfile:

```
...
COPY ./rc.sh /usr/local/bin/
...
```

Make sure your rc.sh is in the same directory as the Dockerfile, also make sure it has execute permissions.